JdbcCursorItemReader vs JdbcPagingItemReader impl and JpaPgaingItemReader and queryprovider
public JdbcPagingItemReader<Point> reader() {

    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Point>()
            .name("reader")
            .pageSize(chunkSize)
            .fetchSize(chunkSize)
            .dataSource(datasource)
            .rowMapper(pointRowMapper)
            .parameterValues(parameters)
            .queryProvider(pagingQueryProvider())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider() {

    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    queryProvider.setDataSource(datasource);
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("place_id, user_id as member_id, points");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("user_point");
    queryProvider.setWhereClause("place_id = :place_id");
    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeyAsc("place_id", "member_id"));

    try {
        return queryProvider.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

It uses the Mysql database. I wrote the JdbcPagingItemReader like this. I expected offset-based pagenation would be applied.
expected)
SELECT place_id, user_id as member_id, point 
FROM user_point 
WHERE (user_point.place_id = ?) 
ORDER BY place_id ASC, member_id ASC 
OFFSET ? 
LIMIT 100

However, if you look at the actual internal code or the executed query, it is read based on a unique key, such as a curator-based one.
actual)
SELECT place_id, user_id as member_id, point 
FROM user_point 
WHERE (user_point.place_id = ?) 
AND ((place_id > ?) OR (place_id = ? AND member_id > ?)) 
ORDER BY place_id ASC, member_id ASC 
LIMIT 100

Then, what is the difference between JdbcCursorItemReader and JdbcPagingItemReader? I know that the two are divided because of different paging methods, but I'm confused if I misunderstood.

Should I understand that the JdbcCursorItemReader uses the cursor function in the database and the JdbcPagingItemReader is implemented to function as a cursor in the application?

SpringBatch Docs says that JdbcPagingItemReader should have a unique sortKey, but JpaPagingItemReader does not need a unique sortKey because JPA supports paging.


Should I use JpaPagingItemReader when I have to sort with a sortkey that is not unique?

finally, Why would this alias be used for the where clause if you were to use an alias to the select clause when creating the PagingQueryProvider?

I thought the aliases were only used in order by when sorting, but it was awkward because these aliases were used in the where clause when they were actually paging.
There was an exception that the table did not have a corresponding column because it was used in the where clause as an alias.
Was it intentionally implemented?
Please understand if the sentence is awkward because I am not good at English.
I already read JdbcCursorItemReader vs JdbcPaigingItemReader , but I am still curious about question 1
